# How to run selenium java testcases and copy test framework from Mac host to Ubutnu Docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, containers

I have  a selenium java test automation framework in my Mac os . Now , I want to execute my automation testcases in Ubuntu Docker container using a docker file which should automatically install java, selenium , TestNG, Maven in ubuntu docker container .

Comment: #1 Do you have knowledge about docker? #2 Are you able to run your selenium tests using the shell without any IDE? #3 Does your selenium open a real browser UI or are you using something like browserstack?

Answer (score 0):

Docker require shell commands so, before thinking on docker, you need to be able to run your selenium tests using the shell. If your test cannot be executed using the shell on your mac, it will be difficult to execute it with docker.

If you are able to run the tests using the shell and al of your reports are well generated, you are ready to docker.

Selenium tests are not live applications, so your docker container will be use just to run the tests and after that, you should destroy it.

As you using java, is there an option to run your tests as a single jar, instead maven. If you achieve this, your flow will be more easy or light.

If you achieve the dockerization of your test, you could run your tests developed in you mac on any machine on-premise or cloud with this line:

```
docker run --name tests -d \
-e PARAM1=FOO  \
-e PARAM2=BAR  \
tests:1.0.0
```

### Running tests with maven (source code level)

If you pom.xml is well configured, you could run your the testng test with : `mvn clean test`

So you docker file will be

```
FROM maven:3.3-jdk-8
RUN mkdir /usr/test
COPY . /usr/test
WORKDIR /usr/test 
CMD["mvn","clean", "test"]
```

**Note:** I'm not tested this Dockerfile yet

The execution will be a little slower because compilation is performed at docker run phase.

### Run tests using jar

According to [this](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/how-to-run-testng-xml-webdriver-tests-from-command-line) you can run testng with pure java:

```
java -cp F:\Selenium\SampleTestNG\lib\*;F:\Selenium\SampleTestNG\bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

As you can see, you need the testng framework jars. That will complicate the dockerization.

If you are able to use the [maven-assembly-plugin](https://github.com/software-architect-tools/stressify/blob/2b0c7d0814e905ef81fb69582b469d2dc29b9d39/pom.xml#L29), maven will merge all the jars in just one. If you achieve this, your automation flow will be:

```
mvn clean package
java -jar selenium-test.jar org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

If you achieve this, your Dockerfile could be:

```
FROM maven:3.3-jdk-8
RUN mkdir /usr/test
COPY . /usr/test
WORKDIR /usr/test
RUN mvn clean package 
CMD["java","-jar", "selenium-test.jar","org.testng.TestNG","testng.xml"]
```

**Note:** I'm not tested this Dockerfile yet

In this approach, the compilation is done at docker build phase, so it is more fast than previous approach

### Common mistake

If your selenium tests opens a browser in you developer machine, you could not achieve this with a single docker container.

Selenium needs a operative system with desktop interface and a browser installed. At developer phase, all of this is performed on you developer machine. On real environments, you have these options

**- ubuntu with desktop**

Is not common but it is possible. If you choose this, you will need to install many browsers (and its selenium drivers) as much as you can test. As this approach is not a shell solution, you will need to install an agent to be executed remotely. Also you will need emulators to be able to launch browser of specific os like safari or microsoft edge. This will be a nigthmare

So basically this is the same of your developer machine but in another network or in a cloud.

**- Selenium grid server**

Similar to the previous option, but more elegantly. Check:

- https://digital.ai/catalyst-blog/set-up-cross-browser-testing-with-our-selenium-grid-tutorial
- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

You are not saved of browser installation, but it is free.

Your test code will be the same, just the configuration change a little bit:

- https://www.mstsolutions.com/technical/execution-of-test-in-remote-machine-using-selenium-grid/

**- BrowserStack ($)**

Basically, is a Selenium grid server private service ready to use which needs a payment (Sometime the time is worthier than money). Just need to point your selenium test to its url. You just pick your browsers and run:

- https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/getting-started/java#run-your-first-test

Also with this service, docker may not necessary because you just need a simple `mvn test or java -jar`. These commands could be launched with a Jenkins or a simple shell script in your devops server.

**- headless browser**

Basically are browsers that run in **background** mode in your shell using your ram. This is perfect if you cannot pay browserstack o configure your own selenium grid server.

The only disadvantage is that some latest javascript features may not be work in this kind of virtual browsers. Also don't support features like printers, camera, or another low level requirement or in which a **real** UI is required.

Here some options:

- https://phantomjs.org/
- https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/12/using-headless-mode-in-firefox/
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome